# How to you do a select statement with an order by when you have a mix of numbers and strings?

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript, jet

The Column is a string, and the data inside of it can be

```
10
2
3
3.1
3.2
a10
a11
1
a12.2
a12.3
```

wanting the results back as:

```
1
2
3
3.1
3.2
10
a10
a11
a12.2
a12.3
```

This would be ASP/VBScript with a MSACCESS web database (Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source)

Comment: And what should the order be?

Comment: just revised to show what it looks like, and should look like

Comment: Is the order by clause different in MSACCESS? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/510c8/1

Comment: @ Jason...this is wrong (Try inserting value 10)

Comment: ok fixed that in the example for future people, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the non-number strings always begin with a single letter like in your sample, you can ORDER BY three column expressions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    IIf(IsNumeric(the_column) = True, 0, 1) AS order_by1,
    IIf(IsNumeric(the_column) = True, '', Left(the_column,1)) AS order_by2,
    IIf(IsNumeric(the_column) = True,
        Val(the_column), Val(Mid(the_column,2))) AS order_by3,
    the_column
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

If you don't want those order_byX fields in your result set, move them into the ORDER BY clause instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    the_column
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY
    IIf(IsNumeric(the_column) = True, 0, 1),
    IIf(IsNumeric(the_column) = True, '', Left(the_column,1)),
    IIf(IsNumeric(the_column) = True,
        Val(the_column), Val(Mid(the_column,2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about MS Access:

```
SELECT IIf(IsNumeric(Left([fld],1)),0,Left([fld],1)) AS Expr1, 
  Val(IIf(IsNumeric(Left([fld],1)),[fld],Mid([fld],2))) AS Expr2, Fld
FROM Table
ORDER BY IIf(IsNumeric(Left([fld],1)),0,Left([fld],1)), 
  Val(IIf(IsNumeric(Left([fld],1)),[fld],Mid([fld],2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to first sort by the length of the field, and after by the field value. Something like this:

```
SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE ORDER BY LEN(FIELD), FIELD
```

It worked here, see if there are another test case that brakes it.